# How to set session through curl in php

Tags: php, session, curl

I have created a script for load test. In this there are 2 curl request to the remote server. First request is for login, if login success then other curl request to adding a new user. In this the first curl request is done but when i call the second request for adding new user it rejects, because session is not set.

In the first call for login i believe the session is set but how do i use this in my second request.

I have seen some answers saying to use cookie jar but i don't understand how to do that. How to create a cookie like in the below code.

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", 'cookiename'); //Plz explain this line
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

[tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)- Generate file with random name in '/tmp' directory with 'cookiename' prefix.

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", 'cookiename');
```

[CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) - Option for setting the name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
```

[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) - Option for setting the name of the file containing the cookie data.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```

Algorithm:

1. In first request you should use option CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to store your cookies;
2. In second request you should use option CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to use stored cookies from the first request.